# Prevent XslCompiledTransform from using self-closing tags

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, html, shorttags

I am using `XslCompiledTransform` to convert an XML file to HTML.  Is there a way I can prevent it from using self-closing tags.

e.g.

```
<span></span> <!-- I want this even if content empty -->
<span/> <!-- stop doing this! ->
```

The self-closing tags on span's are messing up my document no matter which browser I use, though it is valid XML, it's just that 'span' is not allowed to have self-closing tags.

Is there a setting I can put in my xsl, or in my C#.Net code to prevent self-closing tags from being used?

Comment: A span with no attributes or content should be completely invisible.  Would wrapping your span in an xsl:if block to check for content work for you?

Comment: The correct term is self-closing tags.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two alternative solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Though I couldn't classify this as a direct solution (as it doesn't emit an empty element), the workaround I used was to put a space (using xsl:text) in the element -- since this is HTML markup, and if you are activating Standards mode (not quirks), the extra space doesn't change the rendered content. I also didn't have control over the invocation of the transform object.

```
<div class="clearBoth"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try `<xsl:output method="html"/>`,** however the result would no longer be well-formed XML document.

**Or, you can invoke the [XslCompiledTransform.Transform()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163432.aspx) method** passing as one of the parameters your own **[XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx)**. In your implementation you are in full control and can implement any required serialization of the result tree.

Comment: This still generates the invalid <span/>, even with output method = "html".

Comment: @Sheamus: Then you definitely must modify the settings for your XmlWriter and/or write your class implementing XmlWriter, as I recommended in my answer..

Answer (score 0):

In your XSLT use `<xsl:output method="html"/>` and then make sure your HTML result elements your stylesheet creates are in no namespace. Furthermore depending on how you use XslCompiledTransform in your C# code you need to make sure the `xsl:output` settings in the stylesheet are honoured. You can easily achieve that by transforming to a file or stream or TextWriter, in that case nothing has to be done. However if you for some reasons transform to an XmlWriter then you need to ensure it is created with the proper settings e.g.

```
XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();
proc.Load("sheet.xsl");

using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create("result.html", proc.OutputSettings))
{
  proc.Transform("input.xml", null, xw);
}
```

But usually you should be fine by simply transforming to a Stream or TextWriter, in that case nothing in the C# code has to be done to honour the output method in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have been able to find, is to add logic to the XSL file.  Basically if the the elements I wanted to wrap span around is empty, don't use the span element at all.

```
<xsl:if test="count(jar/beans) > 0">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="jar/beans"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Not ideal to have to insert this everywhere in my xsl file, to compensate for the fact that even though I choose output method "html", it more than willingly will generate illegal HTML.

Sigh.