# C# XSLT transformer uses self closing HTML tags which are invalid

Tags: c#, html, xml, xslt

Using C#, I want to transform an xml string to an html string with xslt. However, some tags are transformed as self closing. Actually, this is a duplicate of [XSLT self-closing tags issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887739/xslt-self-closing-tags-issue) and [Prevent XslCompiledTransform from using self-closing tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153938/prevent-xslcompiledtransform-from-using-self-closing-tags) . Unfortunately, could not make it work with the answers given to them. Below is a minimal fiddle.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/zsqent

Current output is

```
<div>
  <div class="test" />
  <i class="test" />
</div>
```

whereas I need it to be

```
<div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <i class="test"></i>
</div>
```

In case fiddle gets deleted, here is a copy of it

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Xsl;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var xml = @"<a href=""#"" target=""_blank"">Click here</a>";
        var xsl = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<xsl:stylesheet version=""1.0"" xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"">
    <xsl:strip-space elements=""*"" />
    <xsl:template match=""/"">
        <div>
            <div class=""test""></div>
            <i class=""test""></i>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>";
        
        var html = TransformXml(xml, xsl);
        
        Console.WriteLine(html);
    }
    
    public static string TransformXml(string xml, string xslt)
    {
        var transformedDocument = new XDocument();

        using (var xsltStringReader = new StringReader(xslt))
        {
            var xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            xmlReaderSettings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
            using (XmlReader xsltReader = XmlReader.Create(xsltStringReader, xmlReaderSettings))
            {
                var transformer = new XslCompiledTransform();
                transformer.Load(xsltReader);
                using (var xmlStringReader = new StringReader(xml))
                {
                    using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlStringReader, xmlReaderSettings))
                    {
                        using (XmlWriter newDocumentWriter = transformedDocument.CreateWriter())
                        {
                            transformer.Transform(xmlReader, newDocumentWriter);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return transformedDocument.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't write non-XML (which is what `method=""html"` does) into XML...  (also that comment is already made in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7156213/477420 you've linked to... so sorry for repeating something you already know)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thank you for pointing that out. I'll remove that line, but still have the problem.

Comment: I'm confused what you want to achieve now... Either "create HTML with XSLT and save it as plain text" or "create some tree and save it as XML", there is no "create HTML and save it as XML" because HTML *is not* XML (there is no support for non-closed tags in XML, in addition to HTML correctly interpreting "self-closed" tags as broken markup). Your edit hints that you actually want XML output - so adjust your expectations as there is no difference between empty and self-closed tags in XML.

Comment: I want to create HTML on the server, send it to client and render on browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

You can use single apostrophes for the XSLT attributes.

(1) XSLT output clause should be as follows:

```
<xsl:output indent='yes' media-type='text/html' method='html' omit-xml-declaration='yes' encoding='UTF-8' />
```

(2) Important parameter to use: `xsl.OutputSettings`. Otherwise, the XSLT settings are not taken into account.

**c#**

```
public static string TransformXml(string xml, string xslt)
{
    string output = String.Empty;

    using (StringReader srt = new StringReader(xslt))
    using (StringReader sri = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        using (XmlReader xrt = XmlReader.Create(srt))
        using (XmlReader xri = XmlReader.Create(sri))
        {
            XslCompiledTransform xsl = new XslCompiledTransform();
            xsl.Load(xrt);
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            using (XmlWriter xwo = XmlWriter.Create(sw, xsl.OutputSettings)) // use OutputSettings of xsl, so it can be output as HTML
            {
                xsl.Transform(xri, xwo);
                output = sw.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```